# How does the Sort Order of Products in Subcategories work?

Tags: catalog, category, products

When adding a product to a category, a sorting order value can be specified.

Imaging now we have a Category "P" set to "Anchor" and various categories "C1" and "C2" which are childs of "P".

How is the order of those products defined, which are only in the sub categories, but displayed when opening the parent category?

Comment: Please view this Stackflow answer 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454282/magento-override-sort-order-of-product-list-by-subcategories

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Indexer_Product::_refreshAnchorRelations` specially these lines:

```
$position = 'MIN('.
            $adapter->getCheckSql(
                'cp.category_id = ce.entity_id',
                'cp.position',
                '(cc.position + 1) * ('.$adapter->quoteIdentifier('cc.level').' + 1) * 10000 + cp.position'
            )
        .')';
```

`cc` and `ce` are the same `catalog_category_entity` table and `cp` is `catalog_category_product` table.

A product can be in more than one child categories so the product position is a minimum between multiple values.
So basically the product position in the parent category is the minimum between the positions relative to each categories from the table `catalog_category_product` following this formula:

```
(child category position + 1) * (child category level + 1) * 10000 + ( product position in catalog_category_product + 1)
```

**[EDIT]**
Conclusion: products in a category with a position higher in the tree will be shown before the ones below.

Comment: I can't compute by hand the exact `position` values indexed in `catalog_category_product_index` (I'm getting numbers much larger), but I get the idea.. @Marius, have you ever tried manually modifying these indexed `position` values? It doesn't seem to affect anything else when I mess around with them on a dev.

Comment: @Youn Sorry I've never tried to modify them

Comment: do you understand the logic behind this formula? It's completely the opposite of how I would have weighed things.. unless, of course, you like to assign large position numbers.

Comment: You also have to adjust `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Indexer_Product::reindexAll`.

Answer (score 1):

As Marius and Andreas suggested, you have to rewrite the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Indexer_Product` class to change the comportement of `_refreshAnchorRelations` and `reindexAll`.

### For `_refreshAnchorRelations`

You have by default

```
'(cc.position + 1) * ('.$adapter->quoteIdentifier('cc.level').' + 1) * 10000 + cp.position'
```

change it for

```
'cp.position + 10000'
```

## For `reindexAll`

You have by default

```
'('.$idxAdapter->quoteIdentifier('ce.position').' + 1) * '
.'('.$idxAdapter->quoteIdentifier('ce.level').' + 1 * 10000)'
.' + '.$idxAdapter->quoteIdentifier('cp.position')
```

change it for

```
'('.$idxAdapter->quoteIdentifier('cp.position').' + 10000)'
```

So it will only take the minimum product position. I have added `+ 10000` because some of our customers enter a negative position.

Comment: hm I do not want to change anything - the question was just about knowing how that stuff works :) thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Note there is a huge mistake between `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Indexer_Product::_refreshAnchorRelations()` and `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Indexer_Product::reindexAll()` methods, which will obviously lead to some strange behaviors:

## In `_refreshAnchorRelations()`:

```
$position = 'MIN('.
    $adapter->getCheckSql(
        'cp.category_id = ce.entity_id',
        'cp.position',
        '(cc.position + 1) * ('.$adapter->quoteIdentifier('cc.level').' + 1) * 10000 + cp.position'
    )
.')';
```

Note that here we have brackets that are surrounding the expression, which gives us this result: `(cc.position + 1) * (cc.level + 1) * 10000 + cp.position`.

`_refreshAnchorRelations()` is a protected method called by the following three methods in the same class:

- `catalogProductSave()`
- `catalogProductMassAction()`
- `catalogCategorySave()`

These last are called when you are saving a category or a product in the backend.

## In `reindexAll()`:

```
$position = 'MIN('.
    $idxAdapter->getCheckSql(
        'ca.category_id = ce.entity_id',
        $idxAdapter->quoteIdentifier('cp.position'),
        '('.$idxAdapter->quoteIdentifier('ce.position').' + 1) * '
        .'('.$idxAdapter->quoteIdentifier('ce.level').' + 1 * 10000)'
        .' + '.$idxAdapter->quoteIdentifier('cp.position')
    )
.')';
```

Here, the brackets surrounding the expression are positioned differently, which give us: `(ce.position + 1) * (ce.level + 1 * 10000) + cp.position`.

With the priority of the operators, the result obtained here will not be the same at all than with `_refreshAnchorRelations()` method.

As its name may suggest, the `reindexAll()` method occurs when you launch the reindexing of `catalog_category_product` index ("Category Products").