# Positioning in anchored categories with subcategories

Tags: magento-enterprise, ee-1.12

I have a category structure like below, where I have products onnly in `LC1` and `LC2`. 
All of the categories are anchored, so you can see all of producsts in `LC`s in any of the higher categories.

```
Top Cat
-- Sub Cat
   -- Lowest Cat 1 (LC1)
   -- Lowest Cat 2 (LC2)
etc...
```

I'm having a problem where product positions assigned in the `LC`s are not working as they are assigned in `Top Cat` and `Sub Cat`. The position values only hold when you are in categories that are not anchoring any subcategories.

This is apparently how product positions work, according to discussions from a while back ([here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/52431/) and [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/79685/P15/)). Some proposed solutions include

1. Assigning the products in `LC`s to their parent categories with same positions values
2. Unchecking "Use Config Settings" of the anchoring parent categories and selecting Best Value (which is the position value). This poster seemed like he had only a 2-tier category structure.

(1) is not an option for us. I tried (2), but it doesn't work. I don't know if it's because we have a deeper category tree. I have seem [Marius's post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7500/how-does-the-sort-order-of-products-in-subcategories-work) that seems relevant, but I'd like to know if there is an option that will allow my product positions values to be displayed according to the position values, discarding how many or how deep subcategories are anchored?

I use Magento EE 1.12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on what [I explained here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/7501/146) I think the best solution to achieve what you need is to rewrite the method `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Indexer_Product::_refreshAnchorRelations` and add your own logic.
I mean, instead of the default algorithm for determining the position:

```
$position = 'MIN('.
        $adapter->getCheckSql(
            'cp.category_id = ce.entity_id',
            'cp.position',
            '(cc.position + 1) * ('.$adapter->quoteIdentifier('cc.level').' + 1) * 10000 + cp.position'
        )
    .')';
```

try to use something like this:

```
$position = 'MIN('.
        $adapter->getCheckSql(
            'cp.category_id = ce.entity_id',
            'cp.position',
            'cp.position'//just the product position here instead of the full expression
        )
    .')';
```

Not sure if the code above works, I didn't test it. I just wanted to emphasize the idea.
After the modifications, rebuild your indexes.

Comment: I forget what I ended up doing last year, but this seems to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for community but not working for enterprise 
for enterprise here is the code

`Enterprise_Catalog_Model_Index_Action_Catalog_Category_Product_Refresh :: _getAnchorCategoriesSelect()`

UPDATE FROM

```
'position'      => new Zend_Db_Expr('ccp.position + 10000'),
```

TO

```
'position'      => new Zend_Db_Expr('ccp.position'),
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

just rewrite Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Indexer_Product

with

```
public function reindexAll()    {
              ...
              ...
              $position = 'MIN('.
                $idxAdapter->getCheckSql(
                    'ca.category_id = ce.entity_id',
                    $idxAdapter->quoteIdentifier('cp.position'),

                    // START NEW CODE
                    // add parent cat-position to calulation
                    '('.$idxAdapter->quoteIdentifier('cep.position').' + 1 * 100000) * ' .
                    // END NEW CODE

                    '('.$idxAdapter->quoteIdentifier('ce.position').' + 1) * '
                    . '('.$idxAdapter->quoteIdentifier('ce.level').' + 1 * 10000)'
                    . ' + '.$idxAdapter->quoteIdentifier('cp.position')
                )
                .')';


            $select = $idxAdapter->select()
                ->useStraightJoin(true)
                ...
                ...
                ->joinInner(
                    array('ce' => $this->_categoryTable),
                    $idxAdapter->quoteIdentifier('ce.path') . ' LIKE ' .
                    $idxAdapter->quoteIdentifier('ca.path') . ' OR ce.entity_id = ca.category_id',
                    array()
                )

                // START NEW CODE
                // join category_entity for parent cats 

                ->joinInner(
                    array('cep' => $this->_categoryTable),
                    'ce.parent_id = cep.entity_id',
                    array()
                )

                // END NEW CODE

                ->joinInner(
                    ...
...
}
```