# Category Products Indexing

Tags: indexing

If I re-index catalog_category_product, shouldn't the tables `catalog_category_product` and `catalog_category_product_index` have the same amount of entries afterwards?

If not, what is the difference or what explains it?

If yes, how come they are still different?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They shouldn't have the same number of records.
The table `catalog_category_product` contains the links you create in the backend. Here is an example.
Let's say you have the following category structure. Using category ids:

```
2
|-4
|-5
  |-6
```

And in the backed you associate the product with id `99` to the category with id 6.
Then in `catalog_category_product` you will have:

```
category_id = 6
product_id = 99
position = 0 (or whatever)
```

Let's say category 5 is anchor and category 2 is root. After reindexing you will see in `catalog_category_product_index` you will have 3 records for each store view where the product is available:

```
category_id|product_id|position|is_parent|store_id|visibility  
2          |99        |P1      |1        |1       |4  
5          |99        |P2      |1        |1       |4   
6          |99        |P3      |0        |1       |4
```

P1, P2, P3 are the product positions.See how they are calculated [in here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/7501/146).
is_parent is 0 if the product is directly related to the category and 1 if it's related to a child category (I'm not 100% sure about this).

Also, from the `_index` table only enabled products appear.

Comment: Thanks. That helped alot! To clarify it even further: Would you agree that they would have the same amount of records if a) the products would always be bound to each category level (so all would be is_parent=0) and b) if all products would be enabled?

Comment: @Celldweller. And if you have only one store view. And the parent categories of categories that have products are not anchors.