# Different formulas for product position

Tags: magento-1.9, reindex, position

We are talking about a class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Indexer_Product`

When you upgrade the product through admin panel, the position of product calculated in `_refreshAnchorRelations()`

[github link](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Indexer/Product.php#L536)

```
$position = 'MIN('.
    $adapter->getCheckSql(
    'cp.category_id = ce.entity_id',
    'cp.position',
    '(cc.position + 1) * ('.$adapter->quoteIdentifier('cc.level').' + 1) * 10000 + cp.position'
    )
.')';
```

You can look about it [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7500/how-does-the-sort-order-of-products-in-subcategories-work/7501)

But when you use reindex shell, like `php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_product` then position of product calculated in `reindexAll()`

[github link](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Indexer/Product.php#L845)

```
$position = 'MIN('.
    $idxAdapter->getCheckSql(
    'ca.category_id = ce.entity_id',
    $idxAdapter->quoteIdentifier('cp.position'),
    '('.$idxAdapter->quoteIdentifier('ce.position').' + 1) * '
    .'('.$idxAdapter->quoteIdentifier('ce.level').' + 1 * 10000)'
    .' + '.$idxAdapter->quoteIdentifier('cp.position')
    )
.')';
```

There is seen in difference the formulas:

1) (child category position + 1) * `(child category level + 1) * 10000` + ( product position in catalog_category_product + 1)

2) (child category position + 1) * `(child category level + 1 * 10000)` + ( product position in catalog_category_product + 1)

`The question`: is this bug or feature?